# How can I extract text to this class ("message": "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to set the 'href' property on 'Location':)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to extract text `mm` from the `class="question-label active"` but not work give me a error.

What is doing wrong ?

```js
/* myfunction declaration */
function myFunction()
{  
  var value = $('.question-label active').eq(0).text();
  window.top.location.href = 'http://' + value;
};

/* DOM ready callback */
$(document).ready(function(){  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span lang="" class="question-label active"><span class="or-output" data-value=" /ss4/county "></span> <span class="or-output" data-value=" /ss4/state "></span>mm</span>

<p>Click the button to change the location of the first iframe element (index 0).</p>

<button class="godd" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<br><br>
```

Comment: Your selector `$('.question-label active')` will return undefined, and `window.top.location` is redundant, you can just use `location`.

Comment: how could i fix this?

Comment: Think about the selector. If you try and style the question label using CSS, how would that selector look? Once you've got that, replace the incorrect one.

Comment: Your selector says find the element with the class `question-label`  and than find an element `active`. There is no `<active>` element.... Next when you fix the selector, the text will be "mm"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the selector to `.question-label.active` in order to select the element that has both a `.question-label` and `.active` class.

```js
/* myfunction declaration */
function myFunction()
{  
  var value = $('.question-label.active').text();
  console.log('http://' + value.trim());
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span lang="" class="question-label active"><span class="or-output" data-value=" /ss4/county "></span> <span class="or-output" data-value=" /ss4/state "></span>mm</span>

<p>Click the button to change the location of the first iframe element (index 0).</p>

<button class="godd" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<br><br>
```

Comment: very thank you , I am very grateful I had no idea how to fix it